# Подсчёт количества работ по проекту

Tags: mysql, php, sql

Мне нужно подсчитать количество работ по проекту. В базе данных есть таблица `project` (там храниться вся информация о проектах). На главной странице будет выводиться информация о проектах и количество работ для данного проекта. 
    Если хранить информацию о количестве работ прямо в таблице `project`, то придётся постоянно её обновлять update. В последствие это будет сбивать кэш и значительно понизиться работоспособность. 
    Как следует хранить информации о количестве работ для каждого проекта? Следует ли выносить в другую таблицу?

Таблица для списка работ:

```
Id_project   Id_work   title_work   id_users
```

Comment: одна таблица на весь проект? хаха

Comment: кто говорил что одна таблица? речь идёт только о проектах

Comment: Где хранится список работ? Для этого есть отдельная таблица?

Comment: Да, для этого отдельная таблица.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT project.project_name, count(project_works.id_work)
FROM project
LEFT JOIN project_works
ON project.id=project_works.Id_project
GROUP BY project_works.Id_project
```

Где project - таблица с проектами, project_works - таблица с работами.

В результате Вы получите

> Название проекта | Количество работ

Comment: Вы считаете этот способ будет быстрее, чем создать таблицу в которой будет хранится id проекта и количество работ. А обновлять эту таблицу я буду через update?

Comment: Я считаю, что вам виднее, какие операции выполняются чаще и насколько критичны сотые доли секунды.

Comment: В первом случае помимо инсерта строки в таблицу с работами, вам нужно посчитать их количество и сделать апдейт в базу (2 лишних запроса). У Вас появляется избыточность таблиц (хранение данных, которые и так можно вычислить).
Во втором случае Вы тратите немного больше времени на выборку.

Выбирайте меньшее из двух зол конкретно под проект.

Comment: Спасибо за помощь.